# Задачка из Codewars

Tags: javascript

```
function multiply(a, b) {
   a * b;
}
```

Comment: Это задача для прохождения регистрации. Если вам непонятно, что с ней делать - читайте книжку по языку, решать реальные задачи пока не получится

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
function multiply(a, b) {
  return a * b;
}
```

Не проще ли загуглить?

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос.